# Removed event handler continues to fire during postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling

After checking and rechecking my code, I cannot understand why the `btnBack_Click` event continues to fire after I've removed the event and registered another one in `Page_Load`

```
btnBack.Click -= new EventHandler(btnBack_Click);

btnBack.Click += new EventHandler(btnPreviewBack_Click);
```

Is it the postback? Is it because I haven't removed the `OnClick` on the aspx?

Comment: im sure it must have been removed.May be your secodn event is what getting fired

Comment: Do you have autoeventwireup set to true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't see exactly where in your [Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) you are changing the `Click` event, however, remember that **absolutely everything** (as far as event handler changes) is "undone" once the lifecycle begins (although events that caused the postback *will* still get executed).

When a postback happens (whether async or not), all the event handlers are restored to their original configuration.

The best approach is to add your event handler changes to the `Page_PreRender` event:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_MustChangeEventHandler)
    {
        btnBack.Click -= new EventHandler(btnBack_Click);

        btnBack.Click += new EventHandler(btnPreviewBack_Click);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It gave me a general idea on how to approach it. I changed the Click event on Page_Load(), now I'm trying in the PreRender and still doesn't quite work but I think I can make it work... Thanks again

Comment: Jesse was right, in the postback all the events are restored. What I did was to change the events inside the `Page_Load` and check for a postback  (`if(IsPostBack)`)